# Jhipster tutorial: Data validation error.

Tags: java, angular, validation, spring-boot, jhipster

After creating the Jhipster from the tutorial from 
[here](http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-mraible/jhipster4-demo//README.adoc) until step *Generate Entities* I get an error when validating the data. 
[image]

The server out output is

```
2017-10-25 12:56:57.045  WARN 13011 --- [  XNIO-4 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : 
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: 
Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Entry> 
com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest.EntryResource.createEntry(com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Entry) 
throws java.net.URISyntaxException, with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'entry' on field 'date': 
rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.entry.date,NotNull.date,NotNull.java.time.ZonedDateTime,NotNull]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [entry.date,date]; 
arguments []; default message [date]]; default message [may not be null]]
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/VwVLBJe2) are my setting for recreating the issue.

my question is then why is a empty object passed when I entered something? What is the architecture of classes so I could debug/handle it my self?

I was looking at `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/web/rest/EntryResource.java` function `createEntry(@Valid @RequestBody Entry entry)` but missed where this was called and where the validation happened.

Comment: as you suspected correctly the JSON object contains the an empty field for the date. Do you know by any chance where the request is build and the JSON object defined

Comment: You could look at your entity service that uses DatePipe from ng-jhipster lib or problem could be in the HTML template or a bug in ng-bootstrap. You could try in another browser

Comment: @gael that was incredible! how did you know it was the browser? after I used chrome it showed the correct date formal. Namely yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss in firefox . The "T" must stay a "T" . Chrome has a date picker. and fields that must be filled. Nevertheless where was this validation implemented and how could this be presentational example for a web app?

Comment: This is default ISO format for dates used in JSON. Chrome is one of the rare browsers to implement date input and it's not very good anyway. I don't understand why you gt this, have you modified generated code or do you use an old version of JHipster?

Comment: I used jhipster@4.10.0 and followed the tutorial bit by bit. I am unsure how this could have happen.

Comment: Maybe you found a bug and should report it on github